# Do antiparticles have their own Fermi surface?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-chromodynamics, chemical-potential, fermi-energy, condensation

I am trying to understand Fig. 1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3800) paper, which shows a quark-antiquark pair forming in a model of QCD with chemical potential:

[image]

---

Is the implication that antiquarks have their own Fermi surface, with energies equal and opposite that of the quark Fermi surface? Or does the "Fermi sea" extend infinitely downward, in which case there would be some other reason that a antiquarks with energy $-\mu$ would pair with quarks at the Fermi surface, giving the $E_\text{tot}\simeq2\mu$ relation in the caption.

Comment: The title is too general, not reflecting the content of the question. The answer to the title is : both particles and antipartilces are points in space for the mainstream standard model so surfaces  have no meaning. The real question about a specific model of QCD has a different answer and has to be addresses by an expert in QCD models. You could try asking at a  more theoretically oriented  site https://www.physicsoverflow.org/

Comment: @anna v A Fermi surface is a surface in momentum space. It has nothing to with particles being point particles. Also physics overflow seems to be mostly inactive these days.

Comment: @DominicElse the figure above is speaking about a quark antiquark condensate , so it is a specific QCD model, you cannot identify fermi surface with elementary particles unless there is a specific QM complex model.